# Создаю страницу на Kohana mysite.сom/страница не работает, подскажите почему?

Tags: php, kohana

В папке views создал php документ portfolio.php, потом создал контроллер

```
class Controller_Portfolio extends Controller {
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body(View::factory('portfolio'));  
    }

}
```

перехожу по странице mysite.com/portfolio не работает :( делал все по инструкции уроков Морковина, думаю вы его знаете. Помогите, в чем проблема?

Comment: А какую ошибку выдает Кохана?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы работал этот адрес нужен файл `.htaccess`

Попробуйте зайти по адресу `http://mysite.com/index.php/portfolio`. И еще нужно в роутерах прописать пути если ваша структура отличается от стандартной `/controller/action/`.

Comment: есть файл .htaccess ток называется exemple.htaccess а когда перехожу по ссылке как ты написал вот что пишет http://mackay.kz/index.php/portfolio

Comment: @Mackay, ``example.htaccess`` надо переименовать в ``.htaccess``

Comment: да переименовал все равно не работает, http://mackay.kz/index.php/portfolio вот видишь что пишет

Comment: тогда еще один вопрос - Kohana 3.3 и Unix система?